# Pure JavaScript toggle for select / deselect all checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the code working in jQuery but not sure how I would replicate it using pure JavaScript?

I want to be able to click a button and select all checkboxes within that div. Then click again to de-select.

Each section will be in an accordion so thinking it may need to use (this) so it doesn't select all within every accordion.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8bgjwu7a/1/)

```js
$('.checkAll').click(function () {
   if ($(this).val() == 'Check All') {
     $('.container-bikes input').prop('checked', true);
     $(this).val('Uncheck All');
   } else {
     $('.container-bikes input').prop('checked', false);
     $(this).val('Check All');
   }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What have tried so far? Please see: [How much effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/3082296)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zhm94sgp/ Always ready to help, though you should provide us **what you've tried**.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the HTML from your jsFiddle. I've changed your code block to a snippet. This should allow you to have an executable example in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, if you want to do a direct conversion you'd want something a little like this.

```js
document.querySelector('.checkAll').addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (e.target.value == 'Check All') {
    document.querySelectorAll('.container-bikes input').forEach(checkbox => {
      checkbox.checked = true;
    });
    e.target.value = 'Uncheck All';
  } else {
    document.querySelectorAll('.container-bikes input').forEach(checkbox => {
      checkbox.checked = false;
    });
    e.target.value = 'Check All';
  }
});
```

```html
<h1>Check & Uncheck All Options</h1>
<p>Check & Uncheck All Options by Button</p>

<input class="checkAll" type="button" value="Check All">

<div class="container-bikes">
  <input class="first" id="Item 1" name="option1" type="checkbox">
  <label class="label1" for="Item 1">Item 1</label>
  <input class="first" id="Item 2" name="option1" type="checkbox">
  <label class="label1" for="Item 2">Item 2</label>
  <input class="first" id="Item 3" name="option1" type="checkbox">
  <label class="label1" for="Item 3">Item 3</label>
  <input class="first" id="Item 4" name="option1" type="checkbox">
  <label class="label1" for="Item 4">Item 4</label>
</div>
```

I've changed each JQuery only bit over to its pure counterpart.

Comment: `e.target.textContent == 'Check All'` is far from equivalent to `$(this).val() == 'Check All'`. If you say something "direct conversion", then make it actually a *direct conversion*. In particular, this question asked to replicate some specific jQuery code. Replicating it implies you don't change the HTML. Obviously, this means that similar changes which you've made elsewhere in your code are also not direct conversions.

Comment: While you've gotten the overall functionality, one of the things that people use questions like this for is to see direct equivalents between jQuery and vanilla JavaScript.If you want to include an additional version of code that provides an alternate implementation, in addition to a direct conversion, that's good, but please don't call something a direct conversion when it's not.

Answer (score 1):

You can select the button by id if you give it an id. See first line of the code below.

You can then select all checkboxes by the class name, see line 2.

Then you can store a boolean to determine if the checkboxes will be checked or not and the text to display for the button.

You can attach a click event listener for the button, and within that you flip the isChecked boolean. You loop through each checkbox and if isChecked is true, set the checkbox attribute onto it, else you remove this attribute. Also, if isChecked is true, you set the text of the button to Uncheck All, else to Check All, by setting the value of the input element.

```js
const checkAllButton = document.getElementById("checkAll");
const checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName("first");
let isChecked = false;
checkAllButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
  isChecked = !isChecked;
  //check or uncheck inputs
  for(checkbox of checkboxes){
    if(isChecked){
      checkbox.setAttribute('checked', true);
    } else {
      checkbox.removeAttribute('checked');
    }
  }
  checkAllButton.value = isChecked ? "Uncheck All" : "Check All";
});
```

```html
<h1>Check & Uncheck All Options</h1>
<p>Check & Uncheck All Options by Button</p>
<input id="checkAll" type="button" value="Check All">
<div class="container-bikes">
  <input class="first" id="Item 1" name="option1" type="checkbox">
  <label class="label1" for="Item 1">Item 1</label>
  <input class="first" id="Item 2" name="option1" type="checkbox">
  <label class="label1" for="Item 2">Item 2</label>
  <input class="first" id="Item 3" name="option1" type="checkbox">
  <label class="label1" for="Item 3">Item 3</label>
  <input class="first" id="Item 4" name="option1" type="checkbox">
  <label class="label1" for="Item 4">Item 4</label>
</div>
```